# Moving the virtual memory space of an x86_64 linux program to facilitate ROP exploration

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, shellcode

Return oriented programming is a technique used to evade DEP or NX stack protection. I am playing around with ROP shellcoding in x86_64 Linux.

The problem is that the memory space of my program and shared libraries seems to be consistently placed in lower memory addresses.

```
cat /proc/26327/maps
7fdc62ff9000-7fdc63196000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 5317651                    /lib64/libc-2.19.so
```

The 12 byte memory address is screwing up my ability to load ROP shellcode because 0's in the memory address terminate the strcpy function that I am overflowing.

I have full control over the system and executable. Is there a way to force shared libraries to be loaded at higher memory addresses so that I can avoid 0's in the address space?

Comment: The addresses of your program and its shared libraries are going to be page-aligned.  Some of the least-significant digits of their addresses WILL be zero.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The ROP-gadgets will probably not be aligned...

Comment: @EOF, perhaps so, but the question is about the load address of shared libraries.  But if there were a way to do it, then it would be via a modified dynamic linker.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: No, it's about the addresses of ROP-gadgets encoded in shellcode not containing `'\0'`-bytes.

Comment: @EOF, perhaps that's what he actually wants, but he *asked* for "a way to force shared libraries to be loaded at higher memory addresses."  I don't see how to interpret that other than as a question about the load address of the libraries.

Comment: It's okay if the lower bits are 0. Like @EOF said, the gadgets will not be aligned.

Comment: I also found [this](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-10/whitepapers/Le/BlackHat-USA-2010-Le-Paper-Payload-already-inside-data-reuse-for-ROP-exploits-wp.pdf) paper. It seems that the addresses are intentionally mapped low and that the process is called "ASCII-armor address mapping" if that is indeed an intentional defense, maybe there is a sysctl option to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more fundamental than that:
When AMD invented x86-64, they made **canonical addresses** mandatory. While you *theoretically* have 64 bits of address-space, current x86-64 processors don't expose all of it. My cpu, for example, tells me it has `cat /proc/cpuinfo`: `address sizes  : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual`. As the upper half of virtual addresses is reserved for the kernel, you can't get rid of the top null-byte in userspace.

Comment: This is disappointing, but thank you for the info! I will just change it up and use memcpy for now.